# Jenkins [Dynamic Choice Parameter (Scriptler)] failing when querying credentials information

Tags: jenkins, dynamic, parameters, credentials

I am bit stuck on why when I run the following script in **Jenkins Scriptler** and the **Script Console** it works, yet when used in the **Dynamic Choice Parameter (Scriptler)**, it fails with the error:

```
Error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: com for class: Script1
```

I can only assume that it is to do with the used class **com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider** is called.

Here is the script:

```
/*** BEGIN META {
"name" : "GetRemoteNasFolderList",
"comment" : "Retrieve a list of folder names (in reverse order) from a remote NAS location.",
"parameters" : [ 'ENVIRONMENT', 'SHARE_PATH', 'FOLDER_PATH' ],
"core": "1.565",
"authors" : [{ 
    name : "Authors Name" 
}]
} END META**/

import jenkins.model.Jenkins

try {
  // params
  def env = ENVIRONMENT // 'DEV" or 'TEST' or 'PROD'
  def share_path = SHARE_PATH
  def folder_path = FOLDER_PATH

  String user_domain = ''
  String nas_path = ''

  switch (env) {
    case 'DEV': 
      user_domain = 'dev'; 
      nas_path = 'nas_host.dev.company.com.au'; 
      break;
    case 'TEST': 
      user_domain = 'test'; 
      nas_path = 'nas_host.test.company.com.au'; 
      break;
    case 'PROD': 
    default: 
      user_domain = 'prod';
      nas_path = 'nas_host.prod.company.com.au'; 
  }

  String user_name = 'myUserName'
  def full_name = user_domain + '\\' + user_name
  String pass_word = ''
  def found = false

  def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class,
        Jenkins.instance,
        null,
        null
    );

  for (c in creds) { 
    if (c.username == full_name) {
      pass_word = c.password
      found = true
    }
  }

  if (found == true) {
    url = "smb://" + nas_path + "/" + share_path + "/" + folder_path;

    println("Url: "+url)
    // println(user_domain+"\\"+user_name+", "+pass_word)

    auth = new jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user_domain, user_name, pass_word);
    dir = new jcifs.smb.SmbFile(url, auth);

    folders = []

    for (jcifs.smb.SmbFile f : dir.listFiles())
    {
        folders.push(f.getName().replace('/',''))
    }

    return folders.sort().reverse()
  } else {
    print("Credential entry not found for ( " + full_name + " )") 
  }

} catch (e) {
  return ["Error: "+e]
} finally {
}
```

Any thoughts, anyone.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: xx for class: yy

Typical error message if your missing an `import` reference, have you tried referencing everything?

```
import jenkins.model.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.*;
```

Perhaps this is what the Jenkins Scriptler and the Script Console do by default, where as the Dynamic Choice Parameter (Scriptler) doesn't.

Ref: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins/issues/174

Comment: Yes I have.  Prior to this post and again for sanity sake.  Same error message.

Comment: Have just tried using a different plugin (Active Choices Parameter) that makes use of Scriptler scripts and is working.

Why I did not try this before, I do not know, but now it bugs me that the Dynamic Parameter does not and what is the root cause.  I should probably just move on and use what works, but there it is, a bug in a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to using a different plugin (Active Choices Parameter) that makes use of Scriptler scripts and is now working.